# Is it bad to overwrite styles in CSS?

Tags: css, performance

Sometimes we try to write the CSS Style Sheet with the less lines possible.

Let's look at this example:

**Note:** Previously `borders` where all `width:1px`, `border-style:solid` and `border-color:#000`

---

**Scenario:**
We want to change:

- the `width` of: R, L and B to `0px`
- the `border-color` of: T to `#ddd`

---

**Code Used:**

```
border:0 solid #ddd;
border-top-width:1px;
```

---

**What did the code above did unnecessarily?:**

- changing the `border-color` of: R, L and B (3 actions)
- changing the `width` of: T (1 action)

---

**Here is the code with 0 unnecessary actions:**

```
border-right-width:0;
border-bottom-width:0;
border-left-width:0;
border-top-color:#ddd;
```

The question is: **should we sacrifice efficiency for less-code/readability?**

Comment: Well, to be hones, efficiency in CSS is not such a big deal: it takes more time to download the CSS file than to render it (unless you're using Internet Explorer)

Comment: Have you measured any difference in performance?

Comment: @greg0ire, I haven't, I am not sure how to test that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The efficiency loss will not be measurable, if any.

It is always better to write well readable code.

And in the end you first example's file size is less, so downloading the CSS is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

> **should we sacrifice efficiency for less-code/readability?**

Yes!  If you want efficiency, [compress your code](https://github.com/volca/yuicompress), but always have a fully readable, easy to modify, clear and to-the-point, source version.

---

And it's usually best to have *zero* inline styles.  If it's just one element, give it an **id** and put the style for it in your CSS file.

Comment: I would think that compressing the code would result in less "efficiency" since it means the browser will have to do more processing in order to uncompress the code first.

Comment: @druciferre, it depends on the compression methods.  Some favor transmission time, and other favor parsing time.  There are also ones in between that help with both.

Comment: @ajax333221, any compression that is done to HTML/CSS will virtually have to be done with JavaScript. So, unless you know of some other way?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, I should have made my reasoning for quoting the word "efficiency" more apparent. By doing that I was implying different people have different views on what efficiency is. In my opinion, the time it takes to render the page once the code is downloaded is more important as most people have broadband and it takes very little time to get the code for a page.

Comment: @druciferre, I did an [example compression](http://pastebin.com/5u6h4FpC) with yui.  The css is from another question here.  See the before at the top, and the after at the bottom  -- that is what compressed css is.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, I'm sorry, but I would have to disagree. That is not compression. That is simply removing the white-space which CSS doesn't care about anyways. We may be getting a bit off-topic with this? Should we move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5968/discussion-between-fakerainbrigand-and-druciferre)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, *rewriting CSS is part of CSS*.

As for efficiency, I don't think you will notice a measurable difference (with the exception of download times) in between the two.

What is important is to **be consistent,** and make your code **readable.**

As for your example, I would have done:

```
border:none;
border-top:1px solid #ddd;
```

Simply because I feel that makes it more readable

Comment: I didn't know about that way of doing it, it is interesting

Comment: Honestly when it comes down to CSS just write out what you're thinking "I want to get rid of my old border, but then I want a top border" and just do it... that is until you realize CSS requires tons nested divs to position anything correctly ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the wrong question. The sample you provided is not going to result in much of a difference at all between download-times or the time it takes to render the page. I think any web-developer's main focus should be on making the code easily readable to at least themselves, and preferably to others.

I would have done this:

```
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
border-style: solid; /* may not be necessary as many browsers use this as default */
border-top-color: #DDD;
```

It's short, and not very cryptic as to what the display is like, and doesn't do anything unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't know that short-hand can be applied to border-width, I guess it is true that "we all learn something every day" :)

Answer (score 0):

As for compression: not sure what the authors meant by it but if you minify the code, the browser at the other end won't "unminify" it to read it like we would want to. Empty space is ignored anyway, and if not there, that probably even speeds up the parsing...